# How to remove "system reserved" partition from a former Windows 7 boot drive now used as secondary, data drive

Tags: windows-7

I've installed Windows 7 on a new SSD and removed the old boot drive and am using it as a data drive.  That old drive has a 100mb System Reserved partition which Disk Management shows as Healthy (Active, Primary) as well as a much larger data partition.  The System Reserved partition is using drive letter E: and the data partition is using G:.

Windows Explorer is showing the System Reserved partition as an active E: drive which is pretty useless since that space really can't be used.  Moreover, I need to assign E: to another drive.  So, what's the best way to remove (or take "off-line") the System Reserved partition so I can re-assign E: and perhaps even recover the 100mb of space it is taking up (though that's less important).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Computer Management
2. Under Storage, select Disk Management
3. Right-click on E:
4. Select Delete Volume

If "Delete Volume" is disabled, then you will have to use something else like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Perfect.  That's what I thought, but wanted to be sure.  Now, to recover the 100mb "unallocated", do I just "extend" the large data partition?  It's giving me a warning that doing so will convert the basic disk to a "dynamic" disk.  I don't care since this isn't a boot disk, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with Disk Management. If you try this with GParted, I could be more helpful. :(

Answer (score 0):

Also, any ubuntu/deb livecd will have 'disk utility' which handles these kind of tasks easily. (no need to apt-get gparted if it's not already installed)